# when manipulating numpy array, I want to normalize differently for each column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I searched for some methods to normalize array and I found how to normalize every column... which is like below

```
def MinMaxScaler(data):
    numerator = data - np.min(data, 0)
    denominator = np.max(data, 0) - np.min(data, 0)
    return numerator / denominator
```

But I'd like to separate every column and normalize each column differently.
Like 1st column with min-max normalization and 2nd column with z-normalization `((x-avg)/std)`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pick each column and act on them individually. For example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(12)
a = a.reshape(3, 4)
a[:, 0] /= 2
```